# Fill gap between 2 point with <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I did an experiment today to see what I can do with `<div>`s. So I made [a simple Paint-like program](http://derek1906.site50.net/file/html_canvas.html), which you can draw with `<div>`s.

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
    if(!mousedown){
        return false;
    }
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;

    drawDot(x,y,ele);

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;          
});
```

This is part of the code. It works, but there are gaps between dots. So I created a function called `fillDot` which will draw a line from point A (last point) to point B (current point).

```
drawDot(x,y,ele);

fillDot(lastX,lastY,x,y,ele);
```

```
function fillDot(lx,ly,x,y,canvas){
    var rise = y - ly,
        run = x - lx,
        slope = rise / run,
        yInt = y - (slope * x);
    if( lx < x ){
        for(var i = lx; i < x ; i+=.5){
            var y = slope * i + yInt;
            drawDot(i,y,canvas);
        }
    }else if( x < lx ){
        for(var i = x; i < lx ; i++){
            var y = slope * i + yInt;
            drawDot(i,y,canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine only when I am drawing horizontal-ish lines. When I draw from top to bottom or bottom to top, there will still be gaps. I found something called [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) which can do the same thing, but I don't know how to use it...

Any idea how to fill all points in between?

ps: I know there is `<canvas>`, but I am testing what I can do with `<div>`.

Comment: You should probably learn <canvas>... it's more user-friendly (it has methods to draw the lines for you) and it's _much_ faster. My browser had a huge drop in FPS after just a few seconds of drawing with your tool. But I guess that if you're just doing an experiment it won't kill anyone.

Comment: @Cheezey - I know how to use <canvas>, but I am just playing with <div>s. ;)

Comment: Oh, ok. I sometimes do totally worthless experiments like this too. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I translated the Bresenham's line algorithm into JavaScript and it works perfectly now!

```
function fillDot(x0, y0, x1, y1){
   var dx = Math.abs(x1-x0);
   var dy = Math.abs(y1-y0);
   var sx = (x0 < x1) ? 1 : -1;
   var sy = (y0 < y1) ? 1 : -1;
   var err = dx-dy;

   while(true){

     drawDot(x0,y0);

     if ((x0==x1) && (y0==y1)) break;
     var e2 = 2*err;
     if (e2>-dy){
       err -= dy;
       x0  += sx;
     }
     if (e2 < dx){
       err += dx;
       y0  += sy;
     }
   }
}
```